# Stop duplication from For loops JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

For security reasons I am unable to post the code I am using however, I have made a mockup of what it looks like.

```
House
   Member[0]
      Name : "blah"
      Age : 20
      Height :160
      Cars[0]
          CarAge: 15
          VIN: 1234234
          Make: BMW
          Colors[0]
            CarColour : "red"
          Colors[2]
            CarColour: "red"
      Cars[1]
          CarAge: 2
          VIN: 1234234
          Make: BMW
          Colors[0]
            CarColour : "purple"
          Colors[2]
            CarColour: "purple"
   Member[1]
      Age : "blahblah"
      Name : 20
      Height :143
      Cars[0]
          CarAge: 15
          VIN: 1234234
          Make: BMW
          Colors[0]
            CarColour : "red"
          Colors[2]
            CarColour: "red"
      Cars[1]
          CarAge: 13
          VIN: 123656664
          Make: Ford
          Colors[0]
            CarColour : "blue"
          Colors[2]
            CarColour: "blue"
      Cars[2]
          CarAge: 2
          VIN: 1865474
          Make: Mercedez
          Colors[0]
            CarColour : "green"
          Colors[2]
            CarColour: "green"
```

```html
var sameBrand = []; 
var sameColor = []; 
var sameBrand1 = [];    
var sameColor1 = [];    
var sameBrand2 = [];    
var sameColor2 = [];    
for(i=0; i<House.Members[0].Cars.length; i++){
for(x=0; x<House.Members[1].Cars.length; x++){
    for(l=0 House.Members[0].Cars[i].Colors.length; l++ ){
        for(j=0 House.Members[1].Cars[x].Colors.length; j++){
            
            if(House.Member[0].Age == 20 && House.Member[1].Age == 20
            && House.Member[0].Cars[i].Make == "BMW" && 
House.Member[1].Cars[x].Make == "BMW"
            && House.Members[0].Cars[i].Colors[l].CarColour == "red" 
&& House.Members[1].Cars[x].Colors[j].CarColour){
                sameBrand.push(House.Member[0].Cars[i].Make);
                 
sameColor.push(House.Members[0].Cars[i].Colors[l].CarColour);
            
            }else{
                if(House.Member[0].Age == 20 && 
House.Member[0].Cars[i].Make == "BMW"){
                    sameBrand1.push(House.Member[0].Cars[i].Make);
                     
sameColor1.push(House.Members[0].Cars[i].Colors[l].CarColour);
                }
                
                if(House.Member[1].Age == 20 && 
House.Member[1].Cars[x].Make == "BMW"){
                    sameBrand2.push(House.Member[1].Cars[x].Make);
                     
sameColor2.push(House.Members[1].Cars[x].Colors[j].CarColour);                  
                }
            
            }
        
        
        }
    
    }
}


}
```

When running this code I end up with multiples and duplications as it is looping through and finding variations of all possibilities however what I need it to do:

**Check that if both objects contain the same values it adds it to an array.

These values should not be checked again as they have been added to the array.

For all others it will add it to two separate other arrays.**
.

Im unable to use any library or functions so would have to be done in **plain vanilla JS**

Comment: Please include a working code snippet with example/mock data. This would help the people trying to help you a lot

Comment: @Y.Gherbi Updated

Comment: Since the code snippet doesn't run for me, It would help if you post the result you get and the result you expect/want

Comment: are `House.Member[1]` and `House.Members[1]` the same thing (just a typo)? I am trying really hard to understand this